# How to play audio in Django ?

Tags: python, django

How To use the audio file of the local system to play in django?

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<link href="{% static 'css/result_style.css' %}" type="text/css" 
rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
  <body>
  <div class="container" align="center"><br><br><br>
  {%  load custom_filters %}

  <h2>{{summary}}</h2>
  <br>
```

This part is working fine while playing this part in simple html code

```
     <p>Click on the audio To Listen Your Summary</p>
                   <audio controls>
            <source src="D:\textanalysis\audio_file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
             Your browser does not support the audio element.
             </audio>
          <div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you storing your songs in a `FileField`?

Comment: I have just one audio to play and I am not retrieving from the database. Is it compulsory to use FileField?

Comment: If you're not retrieving it from a database then don't worry about it.